# how can we get cell state if we use tf.keras.layers.LSTM (tf version is 2.0)?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

In tensorflow version 2 tf.keras.layers.LSTM returns only the hidden state but not the cell state when return_state is checked to be True

Comment: Can you please explain what is you want to achieve. Also show some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

after seeing source code ,I understood that LSTM returns list that contains tesnors of output sequence , hidden state and cell states